# While solving an equation I get 2 answers, but when I substitute one of the answers the equality doesn't hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I solved the following equation: 
$$\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{2 \cdot x + 3} - \sqrt{8 \cdot x + 1} = 0$$
I get 2 answers $3,-1/17$ but when I plug $-1/17$ on the equation the equality is wrong.

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting a link since links may be deleted.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

For your equation must you demand $$x\geq -1$$ and $$x\geq -\frac{3}{2}$$ and $$x\geq -\frac{1}{8}$$ because of the existence of the square roots in your equation. After squaring one times we obtain
$$2\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{2x+3}=5x-3$$ you can only square again if $$x\geq \frac{3}{5}$$

Comment: That doesn't seem to be completely accurate. What I'd say is that for the last equation to be true the right hand side must be non-negative (since the left hand is...) and thus it must be $\;5x-3\ge 0\implies x\ge\frac35\;$ ....not to square but merely for the equation to be possible at all.